# Sandbox violation on second socket send

Tags: apache-flex, sockets, flex3, sandbox

I have a Flex client using a Flash binary (TCP) socket for communication with a Java server.  I have a localhost (Apache) server providing a crossdomain.xml file which is wide open just while I am testing.

My code successfully loads the policy file on startup.

I then connect the socket to the server without any difficulty and send a message and get a response.  All good so far.

However, when I send a second message through the same socket I get a pause of about 12 seconds then a sandbox violation error:

`Security Error: Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: file:///C:/apache_root/ttt1/ttt1.swf cannot load data from localhost:45455.`

This is the same port and socket through which the first message succeeded.

I tried re-loading the policy file before every send, but I get the same result.

Any idea why this might be happening?  I clearly have an open socket at one point.  I am flushing the socket after each send and I tried doing that after each read as well, but the same result.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
If I recreate the socket prior to every call my code works.  I am struggling to believe that this is correct, but maybe there is a Socket setting I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know if you're doing binary sockets the crossdomain.xml is not loaded via http.

Have you checked your apache's access logs if the crossdomain is even queried?

You might get connection from flash via tcp from flash asking for the file on your java server (not using http. It just sends the string "" or similar). Look out for them. If you don't answer them within 3 seconds (or so) flash throws an sandbox violation.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to do when you want to make a socket connection is to load the policy file. This only has to be done once per load of the SWF.

```
Security.allowDomain(host);
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://"+host+":"+port);
```

The request will be made on the assigned port(45455 in your case) your server will have to listen on that port for a request `"<policy-file-request/>"` without the quotes.
When that request is found then you need to return to the client the crossdomain.xml 
with node `<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />`

After the cross domain is sent you need to close the socket on the server side
On the client side you need to ignore the domain response as Flex will handle that however at that time you can reconnect to the socket server. 
At this time you can do your data send/receive.

I have a feeling the reason it actually worked for you is because you were using the connection for the policy file to transmit your data before it timed out.

I would suggest reading up on the new style of crossdomain policies and also reading up on the protocol you are using for your socket server

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the sandbox-policy you used in the compilation process of your swf not on your crossdomain.xml... maybe this docu helps you:[Security sandboxes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html)

But I'm not 100% sure

Comment: do you happen to know how to change the sandbox setting in Flex 3?

Comment: it's the use-network compiler flag: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html

Comment: I have no explicit compiler setting, which means it will take the default of "true" and that means I can get at network resources.  I think this is a red herring.  If it were an issue with the compilation flags it would not work at all, rather than work only once.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of sounds like a cache problem. Perhaps you're pulling the first socket connection out of cache and the second one gets rejected because it's getting a 200 from the server.

You might want to add localhost to your flash security exceptions list for debugging. that will quiet the sandbox errors until you get your piece to it's production environment.